# Variable change and calculation of derivative respect the change

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose I have a function $v(x,t)$ and set the coordinate change
\begin{align}
x&\to\frac{1}{2}(\xi_1+\xi_2)\\[5pt]
t&\to\frac{1}{2c}(\xi_1-\xi_2).
\end{align}
Let $V(\xi_1,\xi_2)$ be $v$ in the new variable.  How can I prove that $v_x=V_{\xi_1}+V_{\xi_2}$?

I have seen this trick in PDE's equation but I don't understand what it means and how it is connected to the chain rule. I mean $v_x$ and $V_{\xi_1}$ or $V_{\xi_2}$ are functions in different spaces.

If needed I can add details.
Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that we can solve for $\xi_{1}$ and $\xi_{2}$ in terms of $x$ and $t$:
$$\begin{cases}
x = \frac{1}{2}(\xi_1+\xi_2)\\
t = \frac{1}{2c}(\xi_1-\xi_2)
\end{cases}\implies 
\begin{cases}
\xi_{1} = x +ct\\
\xi_{2} = x - ct 
\end{cases}$$
This tells us that $$v(x,t) = V(\xi_{1},\xi_{2}) = V(x+ct,x -ct).$$  So, to differentiate $v$ with respect to $x$ we have by the chain rule: $$v_{x} = V_{\xi_{1}}\frac{d}{dx}(x+ct) +V_{\xi_{2}}\frac{d}{dx}(x-ct) = V_{\xi_{1}} + V_{\xi_{2}}.$$